# What is the best plugin to find a class by name using vim?

Tags: search, vim, plugins

I'm trying to leave my bulky IDE behind and I've found that one of the best parts of something like intellij or visual studio + resharper is the ability to look for a class or symbol quickly.

How does the average power vim user lookup a class or method name (grep/regex/other?) and does a great plugin exist for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate tags using `etags -R` and then use `:tag classname` or simply hit `^]` on the classname. And you don't need extra plugins for that, as long as your `tags` is set.

Comment: I have ctags working but what I'm looking for instead is a way to search for a method across a large directory / project (say I find a method is breaking the build and in the stacktrace I see a signature that I want to lookup)

Comment: `etags -R` would let you do exactly that. Maybe (and probably) with some limitations. You'll be able to `:tag classname.method` (again, maybe it won't work for all classes and methods).

Comment: epic! didn't realize I could simply do the :tag method or :tag class (note- the classname.method didn't work for some reason)

Comment: When I have a method name that exists 2x in the same search I see "tag 1 of 2 or more" - but how can I jump to the next option? n doesn't appear to work as I thought it might

Comment: Maybe you want to use `tselect` instead of `tag`? (and `g]` instead of `^]`). As for `classname.method`, are you using `ctags` or `etags`? I've never done any digging on that, but it may be `etags` thingie.

Comment: And yes, I think iterating over tags once you're there is `:tn` and `:tp`

Comment: You're welcome ;-) And the last, but not least — `:help tags` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use for this purpose `rking/ag.vim` plugin and perform the search of a class name by such command:

```
:Ag --python -w 'ClassName'
```

P.S. Be sure, that you've installed `the_silver_searcher`.